# PHP Calculation and Bootstrap progress bar

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

This is part of my code to calculate how many players there are on a minecraft server right now and return that value in percent to the Bootstrap Progress bar so it can do the stuff it needs to do.

```
$playerson = $data[4];
$maxplayers = $data[5];

$percentage = ($playerson / $maxplayers) * 100;

echo $playerson;
echo $maxplayers;

?>
<div class="container">
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: <?php echo $percentage; ?>%;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now my problem is, The $percentage returns 0 all the time. But I don't know why.

This is my full file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
<BODY>
<?php
// your servers ip
$ip= 'hub.exclusivecraft.org';
// your servers port
$port = '25565';
```

I hope someone can come to a solution.

```
function mc_status($host,$port) {
    $fp = fsockopen($host,$port,$errno,$errstr,$timeout=10);
        fputs($fp, "\xFE\x01");
        $response = '';
        $response .= fgets($fp);
        fclose($fp);
  $response = explode("\x00\x00", $response);
return $response;
}

$data = mc_status($ip,$port);

$playerson = $data[4];
$maxplayers = $data[5];

$percentage = ($playerson / $maxplayers) * 100;

echo $playerson;
echo $maxplayers;

?>
<div class="container">
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: <?php echo $percentage; ?>%;">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do $playerson and $maxplayers  return values?

Comment: They return values yea.

Comment: Maxplayers is 700 and playerson differs

Comment: What does var_dump($percentage) return after the calculation?

Comment: int(0) :# That's very weird

Comment: You need to do a bit of debugging. The logic is correct so one of the values must be returning an unexpected value.

Comment: If I replace the $data[4] and [5] with numbers, it does exactly what I want, But when I replace it with the $data. It goes wrong again, I am looking into it now and trying to make another script to do the same thing.

Comment: What does var_dump $data[4] and [5] give?

Comment: That might be the issue, They give string(4) "23"  & string(6) "700" Any way to fix that? I was thinking of using substr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how those values are created. If you have access to the script that returns 
$playerson = $data[4] and $maxplayers = $data[5] then you may be able to fix the problem there.

If not try...

```
$playerson = (int)preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $data[4]);
$maxplayers = (int)preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $data[5]);

$percentage = floor($playerson / $maxplayers) * 100; // floor (round down) optional
```

Basically replaces everything in the "string" $data[4] & $data[5] with 'nothing' so only numbers 0-9 are left and typecast to integer for good measure.

Comment: That works perfectly, I've just removed the floor, because I get very little amounts back. Still, Thanks!

Comment: You could replace floor with ceil and round the results up.

Answer (score 0):

I think your array is empty, in the first step you have only created the array but you did't assign any values to that arrays.
you are just dividing blank array by blank array therefor you get a 0, think about that.